# find the range of $f(x)=e^x/(x+1)$, where $x \in [0,3]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher told the last step using a graph. I didn't get it so I prefer you explain the graph (if made) or use another method. Thanx.

Answer - $[1, \frac{e^3}{3})$

Comment: Okay, thanks for specifying your preference. Do you have a question or anything else? Also, the answer you quoted is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can check $f$ is not decreasing (use the derivative), then $f(x)\in [f(0),f(3)]$ for all $x\in [0,3]$. That is 
$$\operatorname{im}(f)=[1,e^3/4]$$